# UIView's background color doesn't update when panned

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently building a color picker app that would pick a color from user's image.
My picker view's background color is set to .clear for now but I wish to fill it with the color it's pointing.

| My current picker view | What I wish to make |
| --- | --- |
| [My curent picker view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjQex.png) | [What I wish to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ2C0.jpg) |

However the background color doesn't update while panning the picker view.
It's strange because updating the border color works.
I've got something like this.(the value of 'var color' is injected from superview)
Is there a reason why the background color won't update?
Thanks a lot in advance! :)

```swift
protocol ColorPickerDelegate {
   func didMoveImagePicker(_ view: ColorPickerView, didMoveImagePicker location: CGPoint)
}

final class ColorPickerView: BaseView {
   //MARK:- View
   private var borderView: UIView = {
      let view = UIView()
      view.layer.borderWidth = 4
      view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
      view.layer.cornerRadius = 20
      return view
   }()

   //MARK:- Properties
   var color: UIColor?
   var delegate: ColorPickerDelegate?
   ...
   
   //MARK:- Override BaseView
   override func setInit() {
      bounds.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
      let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panColorPicker(_:)))
      addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
      ...
   }

   ...

   @objc func panColorPicker(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
      delegate?.didMoveImagePicker(self, didMoveImagePicker: CGPoint(x: center.x, y: center.y))
      // borderView.layer.borderColor = color?.cgColor : this code changes the color of the border when the view is panned
      borderView.backgroundColor = color // this code even stops updating the variable 'color'
   }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of a UIView is cached in its Layer.  If you change the background color you have to tell the view to redraw.  Try adding a call to `setNeedsDisplay()`

```
@objc func panColorPicker(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
     delegate?.didMoveImagePicker(self, didMoveImagePicker: CGPoint(x: center.x, y: center.y))
     // borderView.layer.borderColor = color?.cgColor : this code changes the color of the border when the view is panned
     borderView.backgroundColor = color // this code even stops updating the variable 'color'
     borderView.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but unfortunately, setNeedsDisplay didn't solve the problem...